# How to resolve Aurelia binding-behavior error after upgrade to 1.1.3

Tags: aurelia

I updated a few libraries including Aurelia-Validation to 1.1.3.

After the update, I am getting this error:

```
Expression 'invite.firstName&validate:validation' is not compatible with the validate binding-behavior
```

Anywhere I use the `validate` binding behavior, this error is thrown.

If I remove `&validate` then the error is not thrown.

I don't see the issue.

Have tried:

Deleting all node_modules and running npm install/npm update

```
"dependencies": {
    "aurelia-after-attached-plugin": "github:aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-after-attached-plugin",
    "aurelia-animator-css": "^1.0.2",
    "aurelia-api": "^3.1.1",
    "aurelia-authentication": "^3.8.0",
    "aurelia-binding": "^2.0.0",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^2.1.1",
    "aurelia-cli": "^0.32.0",
    "aurelia-dialog": "^1.0.0-rc.2.0.0",
    "aurelia-event-aggregator": "^1.0.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "^1.2.0",
    "aurelia-http-client": "^1.2.1",
    "aurelia-loader-webpack": "^2.1.0",
    "aurelia-logging": "^1.4.0",
    "aurelia-logging-console": "^1.0.0",
    "aurelia-metadata": "^1.0.3",
    "aurelia-orm": "^6.2.0",
    "aurelia-pal": "^1.5.0",
    "aurelia-pal-browser": "^1.4.0",
    "aurelia-path": "^1.1.1",
    "aurelia-polyfills": "latest",
    "aurelia-route-recognizer": "^1.1.1",
    "aurelia-router": "^1.5.0",
    "aurelia-syncfusion-bridge": "^2.2.1",
    "aurelia-task-queue": "^1.3.0",
    "aurelia-templating": "^1.7.0",
    "aurelia-templating-binding": "^1.4.1",
    "aurelia-templating-resources": "^1.6.0",
    "aurelia-validation": "^1.1.3",
    "aurelia-view-manager": "^0.1.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "syncfusion-javascript": "^15.4.20",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: What is the `validation` parameter you're passing in to the binding behavior?

Comment: It's the name of the validation-controller. In any case, this issue is resolved now. I wiped my nodes_modules folder and restored my package.json to what it was before the updates, and then carefully added the libs back in and it's working ok now.  Not really sure what happened.

Comment: For anyone else who gets this error, this is a thread on GitHub that discusses: https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/350  As of yet, no concrete answer, but the general consensus is that it's a dependency issue.