# Is it possible to use aurelia-validation with the aurelia skeleton-navigation (esnext-webpack)

Tags: aurelia

I have a project started from the Aurelia ESNext-Webpack Skeleton-Navigation project.  I tried adding Aurelia Validation: `npm install aurelia-validation`.

After installing, I added the following to my code:

**main.js**

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-validation')
  .developmentLogging();
```

**viewModel.js**

```
import {NewInstance} from aurelia-framework;
import {ValidationRules, ValidationController} from 'aurelia-validation'

export class System{
   config = {}; //gets loaded in activate

   static inject = [NewInstance.of(ValidationController)]
   constructor(vc){
      this.validationController = vc;

      ValidationRules
        .ensure(o => o.name).displayName("Organization Name").required()
        .on(this.config);
   }
}
```

**view.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="orgName" class="form-control-sm">Organization Name</label>
   <input id="orgName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value.bind="config.name & validate" />
</div>
```

However, when the view is rendered, I get the following error:

`'config.name&validate' is not compatible with the validate binding-behavior.`

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594006/how-to-resolve-aurelia-binding-behavior-error-after-upgrade-to-1-1-3) that relates to this same error.  However, it references an issue on GitHub that deals with versioning.  It seemed they were all having issues with version 1.1.3 whereas the npm version that is being installed with my project is 1.1.2.

Is there something I need to do to get aurelia-validation working with the esnext-webpack version of the aurelia skeleton-navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/aurelia-validation-notation-res-class-res-property/931/3).  Apparently, I needed to explicitly install aurelia-binding: `npm install aurelia-binding@^1.7.1`